# Ratio of Volume of sphere to Volume of cube

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I was told in my class that the ratio of the area of a circle to area of a square should be greater than the ratio of the volume of a sphere to volume of a cube. But, I am not able to show this.

For the area of a circle to area of a square, I have:
$\pi R^2 / R^2 = \pi$

For the volume of a sphere to volume a cube, I have:
$\frac{4 \pi  R^3}{3 R^3}= 4/3\pi$

But, the latter is greater than the former.

Could someone point out my error?

Thanks!

Comment: But what is given here?

Comment: The radius of the sphere ?

Comment: If the circle is inscribed in the square, then the area of the square is $(2r)^2=4r^2.$  Similarly, If the sphere is inscribed in the cube, then the volume of the cube is $(2r)^3=8r^8$.

Comment: Your error lies in not considering _which_ square and cube we are talking of. You should rephrase the question, for instance, like this: "the ratio of the area of a circle to the area of **the circumscribed** square should be greater than the ratio of the volume of a sphere to the volume of **the circumscribed** cube".